# Python; Multiple two lists together on conditional

Tags: python, numpy

I need to multiply two lists together on conditional statement, here is an example of my base data:

```
x = [0,1,2,3]
p = [0.125,0.375,0.375,0.125]
```

I've been this sum to get a straight forward multiplication of the two lists:

```
sum([x*p for x,p in zip(x,p)])
```

I need to amend the list comprehension sum to only multiply the items together when x <= 2 for example, but I'm still relatively new to Python and can't work this out.

Any help would be great.

edit: 
This is what I'm trying to replicate from R.

```
x<-c(0,1,2,3,4,5)
p<-c(0.18,0.39,0.24,0.14,0.03,0.01)
sum(p[x<=2])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the ternary operator:

```
>>> x = [0,1,2,3]
>>> p = [0.125,0.375,0.375,0.125]
>>> sum([x*p for x,p in zip(x,p)])
1.5
>>> sum([x*p if x <= 2 else 0 for x,p in zip(x,p)])
1.125
```

Or use:

```
sum([x*p for x,p in zip(x,p) if x <= 2])
```

as recommended by SiHa.

---

Following your edit it appears you misunderstood what was happening in R, the code you're trying to replicate is simply summing the values, rather than the values multiplied by the corresponding value in the first list:

```
sum([p for x,p in zip(x,p) if x <= 2])
```

Alternatively, if the first list is always just the indices (i.e. 0, 1, 2, ... `len(p)-1`), this can made even simpler:

```
>>> p = [0.18,0.39,0.24,0.14,0.03,0.01]
>>> sum(p[:3]) # 1 + i (Where i is your requirement, 2 in this case)
0.81
```

Comment: Or, more simply: `sum([x*p for x,p in zip(x,p) if x <= 2])`

Comment: @Siha Nice! Thanks!

Comment: thanks for your response... I've just added in what I'm trying to replicate from R - when I use your sum I get 0.87, vs an outcome in R of 0.81... any ideas?

Comment: @roastbeeef yes, the code your trying to replicate doesn't do any multiplying, try this: `sum([p for x,p in zip(x,p) if x <= 2])`, notice the lack of the `x*`

Comment: oh, it seems I've misunderstood the concept as well as the function in python - thanks for your help and thanks for pointing that out.